# How to round Matrix elements in sympy?

Tags: python, rounding, sympy

**As we know**

```
from sympy import *

x = sin(pi/4)
y = sin(pi/5)

A = Matrix([x, y])

print(x)
print(A.evalf())
```

displays

```
sqrt(2)/2
Matrix([[0.707106781186548], [0.587785252292473]])
```

So

```
print(round(x.evalf(), 3))
print(round(y.evalf(), 3))
```

displays

```
0.707
0.588
```

But how can we round all the elements in a Matrix in a terse way, so that

```
print(roundMatrix(A, 3))
```

can displays

```
Matrix([[0.707], [0.588]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you do not use method evalf with args like `evalf(3)`?

```
from sympy import *

x = sin(pi/4)
y = sin(pi/5)

A = Matrix([x, y])

print(x)
print(A.evalf(3))
```

Output

```
sqrt(2)/2
Matrix([[0.707], [0.588]])
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstand `evalf`. For example, `a = Rational(100, 2) + 0.00001` then what do you think `a.evalf(3)`? Is it `50.000` which is I am asking for? No, it is `50.0`

Comment: `evalf` works fine in this case. Call of `a.evalf(3)` return 3 `significant digits` not 3 digits after dot. To get 3 number after dot write `a.evalf(5)` and you get `50.000`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
# Z is a matrix
from functools import partial

round3 = partial(round, ndigits=3)
Z.applyfunc(round3)
# if you want to save the result
# Z = Z.applyfunc(round3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *

roundMatrix = lambda m, n: Matrix([[round(m[x, y], n) for y in range(m.shape[1])] for x in range(m.shape[0])])

x = sin(pi/4)
y = sin(pi/5)

A = Matrix([x, y])

print(x)
print(roundMatrix(A.evalf(), 3))`
```