# How to round Matrix sqrtm in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

[How to round Matrix elements in sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844884/how-to-round-matrix-elements-in-sympy)

```
from sympy import *
from mpmath import *
A=Matrix([[5,4,1],
          [4,6,4],
          [1,4,5]])
print(A)
print(type(A.evalf(3)))
B=sqrtm(A)
print(B)
print(type(B))
print(B.evalf(3))
```

output-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Matrix([[5, 4, 1], [4, 6, 4], [1, 4, 5]])

<class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/xxx/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_9.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(B.evalf(3))

AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'evalf'

[                 2.0  1.0  3.33606965638267e-20]

[                 1.0  2.0                   1.0]

[3.34095591577049e-20  1.0                   2.0]

<class 'mpmath.matrices.matrices.matrix'>
```

I want--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[2.000  1.000  0.000]

[1.000  2.000  1.000]

[0.000  1.000  2.000]
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to do with the matrix. It seems you want to do some element-wise operation. which is it? square root? integer division by 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `sqrtm` type of matrix changed and you can not use `evalf`:

A: `<class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>`

B: `<class 'mpmath.matrices.matrices.matrix'>`

Use function [`chop`](https://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/mpmath/basics.html#rounding-and-printing) to print matrix `B` in pretty format:

```
from sympy import *
from mpmath import *
A=Matrix([[5,4,1],
          [4,6,4],
          [1,4,5]])
print(A)
B=sqrtm(A)
print(chop(B))
```

Output:

```
[2.0  1.0  0.0]
[1.0  2.0  1.0]
[0.0  1.0  2.0]
```

Additionally you may play with [`nprint`/`nstr`](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/mpmath/matrices.html#other).